# Date Last Run Node Js and Shopify

Tags: node.js, express, shopify, shopify-app

I'm developing a node js app and connecting with Shopify to pull orders. I can set the GET request on a schedule however how do I setup the parameters to get orders since last pull date so I don't keep pulling the same orders?

Comment: What have you tried? We'll need to see your code or any issues/errors you are seeing to help. Otherwise we're just going to point you to Shopify's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to get all orders first, once. Once you do that and process them all, you will have the ID of the latest order. Save that ID. Next time you do a pull operation, you'll note that the API has a query parameter labelled **since_id** that represents the last order pulled. Shopify will return orders since that ID. Again, process the orders, save the latest ID as your new since_id, and continue.